# TypeError: document.getElementById(…) is null

Tags: javascript

I see the following error in firebug:[image: error]  Writing it down so that it's readable:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null


<head><script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/cfform.js"></script>
```

When I click on the link (`<head><script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/cfform.js"></script>`)

I see the following line of code in firebug: [image: code]:

Writing down the code again to make it readable:

```
function onclick(event) {
document.getElementById('catSel2').value=document.getElementById('catSel').value; document.getElementById('busyImage').style.display='inline'; document.getElementById('submitBtn').style.display='none'
}
function (a,b,c,d){var e=La,f,g=Ia;try{f=b()}catch(k){try{var n=Ka(k);b="";k.fileName&&(b=k.fileName);var p=-1;k.lineNumber&&(p=k.lineNumber);var q;
i:{try{q=c?c():"";break i}catch(x){}q=""}g=e(a,n,b,p,q)}catch(w){try{var V=Ka(w);a="";w.fileName&&(a=w.fileName);c=-1;w.lineNumber&&(c=w.lineNumber);La("pAR",V,a,c,void 0,void 0)}catch(I){Ma({context:"mRE",msg:I.toString()+"\n"+(I.stack||"")},void 0)}}if(!g)throw k;}finally{if(d)try{d()}catch(xa){}}return f}
function (){return b.apply(c,f)}
function (){var a=Yd();a?Gd(!0):Wc=X();Jd($,!a)}
function (){var a=Ga(y.document);return 1==a||0==a}
function (a){return{visible:1,hidden:2,prerender:3,preview:4}[a.webkitVisibilityState||a.mozVisibilityState||a.visibilityState||""]||0}
function (){return(new Date).getTime()-$c}
function (a,d){d.apply({},b)}
function (a){a?e.height="0px":x(b)}
function (){b=0;c=s.getTagTime()}
function (){return P.apply(ar,D.concat(b(arguments)))}
function (){return P.apply(ar,D.concat(b(arguments)))}
function onclick(event) {
document.getElementById('catSel2').value=document.getElementById('catSel').value; document.getElementById('busyImage').style.display='inline'; document.getElementById('submitBtn').style.display='none'
}
```

Read another answer to the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885533/it-says-that-typeerror-document-getelementbyid-is-null) by `bits` but he has suggested to make changes in updataHTML. I am wondering what should I be doing in my case.

More Information:

In my actual code, I have line #2 (above) where we are getting error defined in the OnClick event of input tag as follows:

```
<input type="submit" 
       name="submitBtn" 
       id="submitBtn" 
       value="Go" 
        onClick="document.getElementById('catSel2').value=document.getElementById('catSel').value; document.getElementById('busyImage').style.display='inline'; document.getElementById('submitBtn').style.display='none'"><br />
```

Please advise what am I doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: The error is telling you (albeit confusingly) that there is no element with the ID you have specified. It doesn't go into any detail about whether it's the `catSel` or `catSel2` that it can't find, however, but one of them doesn't exist.

Comment: Why do you have two declarations for `function onclick` in that code? And so many "unnamed function declarations"?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thanks a lot. Neither `catSel` nor `CatSel2` was present in my code. I commented that out and the error disappeared.

Comment: @Bergi That code was generated in the Firebug window.