# Selenium-Java-geckodriver : Test Execution halts with JavaScript error as "document.getElementById(...) is null"

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, getelementbyid, selenium-firefoxdriver

I had been encountering this issue for a while now. Browsed through a lot of threads on SO & other forums but still clueless.

While automating a simple flow on a Web Application with Selenium 3.4.0, geckodriver v0.16.1 & Mozilla Firefox 53.0 within Eclipse Neon v2 IDE, I am facing an error intermittently on the console as:

```
JavaScript error: https://www.url.com/my, line 1715: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

Though using chromedriver v2.29/Google Chrome 58.0 or using Python I don't face any such issue.

Once this error appears, the Test Execution halts and finally shows `TimeoutException` as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timeout loading page after 300000ms
```

URL of the website is: https://www.shareinvestor.com/my

The HTML DOM is:

```html
<div id="sic_sitemap">
  <div id="sic_container">
    <div id="sic_header">
      <h1 id="sic_siteTitle">
        <div id="sic_headerMembershipLink">
          <a id="sic_mobileEdition" href="/mobile">
            <div id="sic_loginContainer" class="sic_logIn" style="">
              <div class="sic_login-wrap">
                <div class="sic_logIn-subscribe">
                  <div class="sic_logIn-bg">
                    <a href="/user/login.html">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="sic_subHeader">
              <div id="sic_mainNav" class="sic_withRightCorner">
                <div id="sic_sideBar" class="sic_expanded { selected_market_suffix: 'MY'}">
                  <div class="sic_superBanner sic_superBannerTop">
                    <div id="sic_content" class="sic_collapsed">
                      <div id="sic_footer" class="si_fixed">
                      </div>
```

As of now, I have tried out the following options but of no avail:

1. Java Click
2. JavascriptExecutor Click
3. Actions Click

Here is my code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class 78644072022 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    dc.setCapability("marionette", true);
    WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver(dc);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.shareinvestor.com/my");
    WebElement login_button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='sic_loginContainer']/div/div[@class='sic_logIn-bg']/a"));

    //Java Click
    login_button.click();

    //JavascriptExecutor Click
    /*JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", login_button);*/

    //Actions Click
    /*Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    act.moveToElement(login_button).click().build().perform();*/

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='sic_login_header_username']")).sendKeys("debanjan");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='sic_login_header_password']")).sendKeys("5786");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='sic_login_submit']")).click();
}
}
```

I am looking for a Java Solution with geckodriver to overcome the error `JavaScript error:TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`

In one of the [SO threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885533/it-says-that-typeerror-document-getelementbyid-is-null) I saw a solution like:

> You need to do a null check in updateHTML like this:

```
function updateHTML(elmId, value) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(elmId);
  if(typeof elem !== 'undefined' && elem !== null) {
    document.getElementById(elmId).innerHTML = value;
  }
}
```

Can we implement this? 
Any suggestions & pointers will be helpful.

Comment: have you done console.log(document) and checked it's not null? perhaps you have to access via window.document.getElementById() via the webdriver u use (it's just an idea)

Comment: @dev where are you using document.getElementById() in your code?

Comment: @mtizziani Thanks for the quick look. Can you guide me a bit to set up `console.log(document)` to check it's not null? Thanks

Comment: @kushal. I am not using that. That's the error on the console causing the trouble. Thanks

Comment: @dev you mean browser console?

Comment: @kushal. On my IDE console & I am using Eclipse Neon 2. Thanks

Comment: @JimEvans Can I have your words on this Question please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've managed to find what is causing this uproar in your script.
I inspected your HTML and it seems javascript method `function showRemaining()` is causing this problem; because `showRemaining()` contains this statement

```
    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = '';
```

where it tries to set innerHTML attribute for element having id as `countdown` to ''.

But countdown doesn't exist anywhere on your web page hence the error.

`TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`

and somehow selenium isn't able to look past this error. So I think getting it fixed from developers should help you.

**UPDATE :**

Basically you need to wait all elements to load using implicit wait, once all elements are loaded, then your Javascript error gets resolved and ultimately interaction with the webpage is not hindered by that javascript error:

```
        driver.get("https://www.shareinvestor.com/my");

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        /*String script = "function updateHTML(countdown, value) {" +
                "var elem = document.getElementById('countdown');"+
                "if(typeof elem !== 'undefined' && elem !== null) {"+
                " document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = value;"+
                "}"+
                "}";

        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script);*/

        WebElement login_button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='sic_loginContainer']/div/div[@class='sic_logIn-bg']/a"));

        login_button.click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='sic_login_header_username']")).sendKeys("debanjan");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='sic_login_header_password']")).sendKeys("5786");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='sic_login_submit']")).click();
```

Comment: also if you directly go to login page; it will work; becuase this script causing  error is on your landing page.

Comment: and if you just use chromedriver; then it works well in any case, cause of different browser engines I guess.

Comment: You are right. I am facing this issue in a couple of places. So wanted to get beneath the issue. Thanks

Comment: Yup, I already mentioned with Chrome it sails through without any issues. Thanks

Comment: But it shouldn't prompt your execution using Firefox as you can directly navigate to Login page and start your work from there.

Comment: Can you consider adding a few words about the Solution you offered please? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB :Basically you need to wait for elements to load using implicit wait, once all elements are loaded, then your interaction with the webpage is not hindered by this javascript error; if you go on without implicit wait when the  javascript error is still there which hinders selenium interaction for some reason; but if you wait long enough for wepage to load completely the JS error dissappers & you can resume your interaction with elements

Comment: Actually I did some work around the script which I referred in my Question and which you also wanted me to put in my code. But why have you commented the script in your Answer now? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB: because That JS function doesn't have any impact in your case. The error refers to accessing element that is still yet not present via javascript, yet in your case that javascript issue is being resolved if you wait for few moments using implicit wait for elements to load

Comment: Can you please help me understand why you are suggesting `ImplicitlyWait` as a solution to this issue. I am not facing any `elementNotFoundException` anyway. Thanks

Comment: There is a javascript function running on your website which tries to set innerHTML of an element having ID `"Countdown"` by executing `document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = '';`. There Javascript error is caused by this statement because when that js function executes element is not loaded onto DOM; but if you wait using `ImplicitWait`, that elements loads and is removed later using `$('#countdown').remove();`

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a Java Solution with geckodriver to overcome the error JavaScript error:TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

To answer your question, I don't believe there's anything you can do to "fix" this via Java/Selenium. This is a JavaScript error, which originates from the website that you are trying to access. You might want to consider [contacting](http://www.shareinvestor.com/support/index.html#/?type=contact) their support team, maybe one of their developers can look at this issue.

---

Instead of clicking on the login button, maybe consider navigating directly to the login page?

```
driver.get("https://www.shareinvestor.com/user/login.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**, Those javascript errors are not triggered due to any of the selenium code. Ofcourse, the timeout has been triggered by the selenium(will discuss on this on a later point).

You will get that javascript error irrespective of any kind of browser you launch the URL with. But in case of the gecko, you are notified in the eclipse console with but not in case of Chrome. If you need to see the java script error in chrome, just launch the url in chrome and go to devtools/console(F12). You can also see the same in firefox console too.

- Chrome Img:

[image: Error shown in Chrome console]

**Secondly**, We are getting timeout exception because the site is really taking too much time to load. I have been waited for 7 minutes and the page is still loading even now. Selenium won't executes its script unless the page has been completely launched. As a result we are getting timeout exception(not sure about the default page launch time permitted). I thought of bypassing directly to the login page ("https://www.shareinvestor.com/user/login.html") and that's also not taking any finite time to load completely.

**Intepolation**: Those java script errors are not an issue for automation But those page loads are really. This site doesn't seems like a good candidate for automation with this issue.

**Update1:** otherwise we can also stop the page loading via another thread like sending "esc" key sequence using Action class.

**Update2:** I tried the same code today and it works fine. Below is the code snippet that i have tried(There is no change at all)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "F:\\Softwares\\Selenium\\Webdriver\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.shareinvestor.com/my");
    WebElement login_button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='sic_loginContainer']/div/div[@class='sic_logIn-bg']/a"));

    //Java Click
    login_button.click();
    System.out.println("In Login PAge");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='sic_login_header_username']")).sendKeys("debanjan");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='sic_login_header_password']")).sendKeys("5786");
    System.out.println("Entered password");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='sic_login_submit']")).click();
}
```

Selenium version - 3.4.0

Gecko driver - v0.16.1(mine is 32 bit)

Mozilla - 51.0.1 (Update=>It's working on 53.02 also)

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: I understood the problem, so what can be a solution to overcome/tackle this issue through Selenium/Java binding? Thanks

Comment: It would be unfair to term it as an issue. As I mentioned in my Question, through Chrome Browser or Python/Ruby bindings I don't face this hurdle. Even Node.js have a way out. But, I am looking for a solution from Java/Mozilla binding perspective. Thanks

Comment: what i meant is... it's now working in mazilla.. When yesterday i was trying it didnt even worked in chrome. Now its working on both firefox and chrome

Comment: Thanks for your support and time helping me in this research.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the XPath for the `login_button` is incorrect:

```
By.xpath("//div[@id='sic_loginContainer']/div/div[@class='sic_logIn-bg']/a");
```

Should be:

```
By.xpath("//div[@id='sic_loginContainer']/div/div/div[@class='sic_logIn-bg']/a");
```

---

<strike>This may explain the `TimeoutException`, since Selenium is unable to locate the non-existent element.</strike> EDIT: My mistake, you should see a `NoSuchElementException` if the element cannot be located.

As for the JavaScript error, unless you were trying to use Selenium to access the web element being manipulated by the JavaScript code (`id='countdown'` element), Selenium should just ignore the error. Otherwise, there's the potential for other Selenium errors, such as `StaleElementReferenceException`, but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Can you consider helping me to understand why you felt `XPath for the login_button is incorrect`. I have already mentioned the **actual URL** in the Question area for **direct access to the HTML DOM**. If my `xpath` had been incorrect then I would have encountered `NoSuchElementException` which is not the case. Thanks

Comment: Your code snippet is incorrect then, I based the XPath on that. Also, you are correct that you should get a `NoSuchElementException` if the element cannot be located, it's been a while seen I've used Selenium...

Comment: I have updated the HTML DOM with proper formatting conditions for your reference. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is due to your application HTML page using the async javascript and it uses some variable reference that is not available at the time of execution. we had same issue and asked developer to follow some best practices for javascript in the HTML like putting the script tag at end of the page. I have checked the HTML page source of the site and it contains many script tags in between the code. This will block the DOM rendering. Better, ask the developer to follow some best practices to include script tag in HTML. you refer the link [Where should I put <script> tags in HTML markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup) for the best practices.

Comment: Can you consider helping me to understand what exactly you meant by `async javascript` and `variable reference that is not available at the time of execution` please? Thanks

Comment: Async JavaScript is nothing but script tag with asyn attribute. It will download JavaScript library from source at the time of page loading and execute it once it gets downloaded. The reference variable is a refer some HTML element which is generated by the JavaScript which is from another library